# How to set a timer (countdown) in Manipulate what stops it running?

Tags: manipulate, timing

I have a Manipulate function with 2d slider which I can play with some curves. I consider this as a game (gamification in physics). I want to set a timer so when it countdown to zero then the game stops and I cannot change the slider. or something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Perhaps you can show an example code of what you can try? This will help others in providing solutions to your question.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Using `Trigger` to trigger/pause/reset the timer:

```
DynamicModule[{time, lim = 10.}, 
 Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[θ + d[[1]]], Sin[θ + d[[2]]]}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> color, ImageSize -> Small],
  Row[{Dynamic @ PaddedForm[Round[1. - time, .001], {3, 3}], Spacer[5], 
    ProgressIndicator[Dynamic@(1 - time), {0, 1}], 
    Control[{{time, 0, ""}, 0, 1, Trigger[##, DefaultDuration -> lim] &}]}],
  {color, Red, Enabled -> Dynamic[time < 1]}, 
  {{d, {Pi/2, Pi/3}, "d"}, {0, 0}, {Pi, Pi}, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
     Enabled -> Dynamic[time < 1]}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {d, color, time}]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
DynamicModule[{t, lim = 10}, 
 Manipulate[ ParametricPlot[{Sin[θ + d[[1]]], Sin[θ + d[[2]]]}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> color , ImageSize -> Small],
  Dynamic[Row@{"  time  ", ProgressIndicator[ 1 - (t = Clock[{0, 1}, lim, 1])]}],
  {color, Red, Enabled -> Dynamic[t < 1]}, 
  {{d, {Pi/2, Pi/3}, "d"}, {0, 0}, {Pi, Pi},
   Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> Dynamic[t < 1]}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {d, color}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `Enabled`

Comment: I like this solution but noticed something that may need to be addressed:  if you hold down the button for "d" and keep it held down, then it doesn't "respect" the timer.  In other words, even after the timer has expired, you may continue manipulating the graph.

Comment: @MarkR, excellent observation. I cannot think of a fix right now.

Comment: @MarkR are you a play-tester? Haha! Do you find it works(or doesn’t work) for any other key being held?

Comment: I do seem to have a knack breaking things!  If I actively press and hold on the color, it also doesn't respect the timer.

Comment: Thanks I like it, but for me it's important to find a solution when I hold the slider but the time expired then stop to work. If you have any suggestion pls feel free to share with me. @kglr

Comment: Perhaps you can implement something that regularly checks whether the time has run out or not, and give this precedence above the events triggered by the user interactions?

Comment: and how should I set a reset button for this?

Comment: @Aaron, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr omg thank you very much

Comment: can I ask if you can solve how to freeze immediately the slider when time expired not only when I release the slider, pls?

Comment: @Aaron, unfortunately I don't know how to fix that issue. I suggest you update your question with the requirement that controls are disabled when time runs out even when the mouse is kept down continuously.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're asking for?

```
timeLimitedManipulator~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
timeLimitedManipulator[var_, dom_, {timer_, lim_}, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Manipulator[
   Dynamic[var, If[! TrueQ[timer >= lim], Set[var, #]] &],
   dom, 
   ops
   ];
DynamicModule[
 {t, limit = 3},
 DynamicWrapper[
  Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[n*π*x], {x, 0, 2 π}],
   {{n, 1}, timeLimitedManipulator[n, {.1, 5}, {t, limit}] &}
   ],
  t = Clock[{0, limit}, limit, 1]
  ]
 ]
```

Basically I wrap a timer around my `Manipulate` and force the variable `n` to be updated by a `Manipulator` that listens to this timer